# WP API Get Post Tags

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tags, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

Trying to get post tags with wordpress API - api call is /wp-json/wp/v2/posts

```
ourHTMLString += '<i class="fa fa-tags">"' + postsData[i].tags + '"</i>';
```

It is returning these values

```
"tags": [
        766,
        19,
        578
],
```

I need the tag name and href to this, not sure how to get this. I have tried  `postsData[i].wp:term[i].tag.name` - cannot find a solution. Any help? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to do another request to get this and use **include** to list only theses tags.
eg: /wp-json/wp/v2/tags?include=766,19,578

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/tags/

Answer (score 1):

Send a request to the Wordpress site with the tag's id:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/TagID
```

REF : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/tags/#definition

> ## Definition
>
> GET /wp/v2/tags/
>
> ## Example Request
>
> $ curl http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/

Comment: that just brings an ID, no? need string name field

Answer (score 0):

If we need tags in same API call we can add a custom field in our response.

we can add following code in theme's function.php file

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'bs_rest_api_hooks');
function bs_rest_api_hooks() {
    register_rest_field(
        'post',
        'mtags',
        array(
            'get_callback' => 'm_get_tags',
        )
    );
}
function m_get_tags($object, $field_name, $request) {

    $tags = get_the_tags($object["id"]);

    return $tags;
}
```